# JQuery: Accessing a DOM's attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading with a PHP script a description text on a div, and I've got another script (this time with JQuery) to expand that div and show it's information.

When I want to access the data-text attribute that saves the text (which has the text loaded from the previous PHP), it just shows nothing. I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    // Amplicación de fichas de imágenes
    var selected;

    $(".img_cont").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("img_cont_amp")) {
            if ($(selected).hasClass("img_cont_amp")) {
                $(selected).removeClass("img_cont_amp");
                $(selected).addClass("img_cont");

            }
            $(this).removeClass("img_cont");
            $(this).addClass("img_cont_amp");
            selected = $(this);

        } else {
            $(".ficha_texto").remove();
            $(this).removeClass("img_cont_amp");
            $(this).addClass("img_cont");
        } * *
        var text = $(this).attr("data-text"); * *
        $(this).append("<div class='ficha_texto'>" + text + "</div>");

    });
});
```

The bold part is what fails. If I try to read the data-text attribute with an alert(), it just shows "undefined".

This is the DOM element that my PHP code generates:

```
<div id="img_2" class="img_cont">

                     <img class="image" data-text="Sample text" title="Sample text" src="images/uploaded/ft_7UIC.jpg">

                 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

There is no bold formatting in the code example, but if you are trying to access the

```
<img class="image" ...>
```

block, then you need to use the following selector:

```
$(".image")
```

This is because you are trying to select on the class "img_cont", whereas your img element has a class "image".

To get the "data-text" value, you will need to do:

```
$(".image").attr("data-text")
```

Or if you are using jQuery >=1.4.3:

```
$(".image").data("text")
```

Comment: He could also use the attribute selector: `$("[data-text]").data("text")` to make sure he hits the right element.

Answer (score 3):

try simply this,

```
  var t= $(this).attr("data-text");
```

Answer (score 2):

It can also be

```
var text = $(this).data("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it! I already found the answer.

I was pasting the attribute values into the  instead of the  which is where I'm pointing at in the JQuery code, so the $(this) selector just won't get anything when aiming at "data-text".

Now the attributes and their values are pasted into the container, so the attribute can now be accessed correctly.

Thank you for your answers, though!

Answer (score -1):

To make it work I had to add your class to the code

```
<img class="image img_cont" data-text="sample description text" title="sample title" src="images/uploaded/sample_image1.jpg">
```

And then, your call to attr was wrong (extra parenthesis), and also I changed the append to after so you could see the text (if you append on a img tag you won't see anything). This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


// Amplicación de fichas de imágenes
var selected;

$(".img_cont").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("img_cont_amp")){
          if($(selected).hasClass("img_cont_amp")){
              $(selected).removeClass("img_cont_amp");
              $(selected).addClass("img_cont");

          }
        $(this).removeClass("img_cont");
        $(this).addClass("img_cont_amp");
        selected = $(this);

    } else {
        $(".ficha_texto").remove();
        $(this).removeClass("img_cont_amp");
        $(this).addClass("img_cont");
    }
    var text = $(this).attr()("data-text");
    $(this).append("<div class='ficha_texto'>"+text+"</div>");

 });
});
```